# Is there anyway to hide menubar items in MacOS?

Tags: macos

I know I can "auto hide menu bar" in system preferences, however, what I like to do is hide items like this repository.

https://github.com/dwarvesf/hidden

This repository can hide items on right, but I wonder if I can hide left items (which are application menus).

Any idea is appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As for application menus on the left, those can't be hidden, I'm pretty sure.

Applications often have the option to enable or disable their menu bar helper app in the main preferences. If that doesn't help, e.g. if it's a full-fledged menu bar app, not just a helper, then to my knowledge the only solutions are **Hidden Bar**, which you mentioned, and [**Bartender**](https://www.macbartender.com/).

I'm using the latter, and it does a very fine job. You have four options in Bartender's preferences:

1. Show (default macOS behavior)
2. Hide (menulet will be hidden in a special Bartender secondary menu bar, accessible via the triple-bullet icon ··· on the far right)
3. Always show (menulet will be visible in the main macOS menu bar as well as the secondary Bartender menu bar at the same screen position)
4. Always hide (menulet will be completely hidden)

Some older menulets seem to switch their position occasionally, e.g. after wake-from-sleep, and Bartender isn't yet able to fix the position of BitBar instances. But for the vast majority of menu bar apps and helpers it will work just fine.

Comment: Thank you very much, it is unfortunate but bartender's 2nd option seems great. Ill give it a try!

Comment: (1) You can in fact also modify the content of application menus by hacking the executable or injecting a dynamic library, so maybe there's even a way to "hide" an existing menu by removing the menu title's text string. The menu would then still be there, but extremely slim, without a title in the menu bar itself. But that would (a) be quite hard, (b) different for every app, and (c) break the code-signature integrity of the app bundle, possibly also leading to loss of functionality or bugs.

Comment: (2) Another idea would be for someone to create a tool similar to what the app MenuEclipse is doing which slightly dims the menu bar using an always-on-top black image the size of the menu bar, only with transparency. You could make something similar, only without transparency, with a different overlay image "preset" per foreground app to obscure certain menus on the left side of the screen. But that would probably look nasty, because the menu bar itself has transparency, and to my knowledge you can't completely disable menu bar transparency.